# &(float){0} as a float* argument: what it means?

Tags: c

`&(float){0}`

I came across that in some C code. It was specified as a `float*` argument in a function. What does it mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Taking address of temporary (compound literal) parameter in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927219/taking-address-of-temporary-compound-literal-parameter-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

It's a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

```
foo(&(float){0})
```

is a shorthand for

```
float x = 0;
foo(&x);
```

The only difference between those is that with a compound literal it's impossible to access the number after the call (which matters if `foo` changes it).

Comment: That said, the `&(float){0}` argument is very likely a workaround for a missing `NULL` argument check within `foo()`: The effect is that of simply discarding whatever `foo()` decides to write to that memory location.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Indeed, it seems to be related to passing NULL. Could you elaborate a bit more, and add as answer?

Comment: @Danijel I would prefer if HolyBlackCat added this to their answer. I feel that it's not enough to warrant an answer of its own (otherwise I would already have added one), but interesting enough to have it mentioned. But I HolyBlackCat does not want to do it, I might add an answer of my own.

Comment: @Danijel: the point is that usually you pass a pointer to a valid place in memory, so that the called function can write something to that place in memory. When you pass a reference to a compound literal, it means you don't have means of accessing this data afterwards.

Comment: @Groo ... unless `foo()` stores the pointer somewhere as a side effect. That would be insane, of course, seeing that the compound literal lives on the stack and goes Poof! at the end of its scope. But, if I have learned one thing, it's this: There is absolutely nothing that's insane enough to prevent it from being done in some production code anyways.

Comment: @cmaster: lol, that's a good point, yes. [I'll just store this pointer into a static variable, what could go wrong, right?](https://xkcd.com/292/) Though, with `float x = 0; foo(&x);` , it would also be weird if `foo` decided to store the keep the reference.

Comment: it is used when function requires a reference but we want to pass the constant expression. Such a small workarond.

Comment: @P__J__ Well, in C there's only pointers, and pointers are allowed to be `NULL`. If the information that's supposed to be returned via the argument is indeed optional to the caller, then `foo()` should check its argument and not write to it if the pointer is `NULL`. That's usually just prefixing the assignment with `if(out_arg) *out_arg = ...;`, and allows `foo()` to be called with `foo(NULL)` to concisely signal the intent that the out-arg is not needed. This should be preferred over passing in dummy args all over the code. Different story if ignoring the out-arg is always a bug, though.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica no it will never be NULL only the **valid** address of the compound literal. NULL is not the case here. `&(float){0}` will never be NULL

Comment: @P__J__ You didn't understand what I was saying. What I was trying to say: If the use of the output argument is optional, this should be implemented via a `NULL` check within `foo()` and a call that explicitly passes `foo(NULL)`. No compound literal is used in that case. `foo(&(float){0})` is only needed in the case that a) the argument is optional, b) `foo()` has no such `NULL` check, and c) you are powerless to add that check for whatever reasons.

Comment: @Groo If `foo()` only needs the pointer for storing something in the location and does not use the existing contents of the location (i.e. it is OK for the contents to be indeterminate), then passing a pointer to a compound literal instead of a pointer to an uninitialized object would be a waste of code. Better just to create a local variable in a block with the call to `foo()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to pass the constant expression to the function which expects the reference.

Example

```
float sq(float *f)
{
    *f = *f * *f;
    return *f;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", sq(&(float){3.0f}));
}
```