# Understanding Pointers and Scope in C With Different Compilers

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, optimization, scope

I have recently encountered an issue with how gcc compilers handle a pointer in some legacy code. Taking the below as a quite cut down example of how the code is set up:

```
int someCondition; // Set elsewhere.

static void aModifyingFunc(uint32_t* pArray);

void someFunc(void)
{
    uint32_t* pArray = NULL;

    if(someCondition == 1)
    {
        pArray = (uint32_t[]){1u, 2u, 3u};
    }
    else
    {
        pArray = (uint32_t[]){4u, 5u, 6u};
    }

    aModifyingFunc(pArray);
}

static void aModifyingFunc(uint32_t* pArray)
{
    // do something here with pArray
}
```

One compiler passes the value of pArray to aModifyingFunc correctly and aModifyingFunc does everything as expected. Another later version appears to trample all over the memory to which pArray is pointing. aModifyingFunc is static so should be inline here.

Is this a compiler bug with the new / old compiler? Or is this an issue with how the code is written?

Answer (score 4):

The expression `(uint32_t[]){1u, 2u, 3u}` is called a *compound literal* in C.

You created a compound literal inside a block and then you attempted to use it outside the block, which is not allowed because its scope is only the block.

See [Compound literal lifetime and if blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880638/compound-literal-lifetime-and-if-blocks)

Comment: Scope is for names (identifiers). It is irrelevant here because compound literals do not have names. Lifetime is the applicable concept. These are different things; scope is for place and names; lifetime or storage duration is for time and objects. The assertion that a compound literal cannot be used outside the block it is created in is incorrect; automatic compound literals can be passed by address to subroutines, and thus can be used in code essentially anywhere in the program, as long as that use occurs before the end of execution of the block with which the compound literal is associated.